# Motor problems in 60051

Tags: motor, trains, power-functions

The motor in my High Speed Passenger Train set (60051) has stopped working properly. I just put brand new batteries in and it acts just like if they were worn. Moreover, the little brown capacitor inside the assembly gets VERY hot and after just a few seconds of running, the motor stops entirely.

I have a hard time reading the numbers on the capacitor, but I think it says RO40017 70395. I can't find anything on the Internet on that. I was hoping to buy a new capacitor to replace it, since  I think it is broken.

So, could it be the capacitor? Might it be the motor?
I have tried it directly on the battery pack and I have tried with the 'step' thing and the remote control, both same results: Hot capacitor, motor stops running.

Edit: Upon request, a photo:
[image]

Comment: Could you show a picture of the opened up motor? I think what you call a capacitator might actually be a thermistor. As a current overload protection, they are supposed to get hot and provide resistance according to their temperature...

Comment: @MichaelVerschaeve The problem, as I see it, is that it gets super hot almost instantly. As in so hot that the plastic casing becomes rather warm after much less than a minute.

Comment: Yes, but the thermistor is doing what it's supposed to do, limit the current. You're getting too much current because something in the inner motor itself has worn down or the motor is somehow stalled... I would write this of and replace the motor as its not a good idea safety wise to short a thermistor. You could contact Lego support and see if they'll replace the motor (for a new set they would do so happily, but this set is unfortunately already retired so I don't know)

Comment: Heh, me trying to sound like I know what I'm talking about :D There must be something wrong inside the motor then. It spins freely when I turn it though.

Answer (score -2):

Contact LEGO customer service, they might be able to receive you a new motor for free.

For Bricklink users: [here is the listings page](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=87574c01) to buy this exact kind of motor, in both "new" and "used" conditions.